# Tips for Identifying Query Patterns and Creating REST Endpoints for a Database Wrapper Microservice

Tags: rest, microservices, api-design, data-access, query-analyzer

We're trying to move some direct access to our team's database by some internal teams behind a microservice.

We've collected sample queries to find common patterns for REST endpoints, but it's turning out to be a bit tougher than we originally thought. For those who have done a similar task,  do you have any recommendations as to how to approach this? Are there automatic tools that can look at a bunch of queiries and output something useful regarding their usage patterns?